# How can I change QT listview background from delegate?

Tags: qt, delegates

I have a `listview` in my form and I have an item delegate for it. What I need to do is changing the item's background color in terms of something, from my item delegate.

Ok let's say I have a Listview and I filled it with this list

```
"Blue",
"Red",
"Green"
```

On the other hand I have an Item delegate for my listview. I need to change those items' background  colors with their own colors.

Comment: What we need is you to explain what you want a little more. Otherwise someone will flag your question as "too generic".

Comment: So you want make something like conditional formatting?

Comment: yeah something like that i have some conditions for changing background color. But as i said i am new in qt. and i dont know how to change background color item by item from the delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite the `paint(self, painter, option, index)` function in your delegate in order to change the way the items are painted.

For instance:

```
class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):

    #...

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        painter.save()                   # You can restore the original painter later.
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.red)) # Set background color.
        painter.restore()                # Restore the original painter.
```

What now?

Now that you know how to paint the background you need to get the value of the item being painted so you can decide what color will be. For that you can use the last argument of the `paint` function, `index`, this is a [QModelIndex](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmodelindex.html) instance that you can use for getting the value you're looking for.

Comment: I did like this painter->save();
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
    painter->drawRect(option.rect);
    painter->restore(); But option.rect gives me whoole rect of listview. Do you know how can i get items rect only